# Stopping the method from calling :after

Tags: common-lisp, qualifiers, multimethod

Say I have a code setup like the one below

```
(defgeneric move (ship destination))

(defmethod move (ship destination)
  ;; do some fuel calculation here
)

(defmethod move :after ((ship ship) (dest station))
  ;; do things specific to landing on a station here
)

(defmethod move :after ((ship ship) (dest planet))
 ;; do things specific to landing on a planet here
)
```

Let's now say I want to move my space ship to a station, but the fuel calculation results in a negative amount of fuel on the ship (i.e. there's not enough for the trip).

Is there then a way for me to prevent the `:after` qualifier from getting called without necessarily signalling an error condition?

If I don't stop the call, the ship will be moved to the new location without any fuel getting subtracted, which essentially breaks the game.

Comment: You probably should move the fuel calculation to an `:AROUND` method and turn the two `:AFTER` methods into primary methods.

Comment: @jkiiski how then do I stop the primary methods from being called?

Comment: You just don't call it. `:AROUND` methods have to use `CALL-NEXT-METHOD` manually to call the primary method, so you can have something like `(when (sufficient-fuel) (call-next-method))`.

Comment: Oh okay, but don't :around get called on both sides of the main method?

Comment: The primary method is called by the call to `CALL-NEXT-METHOD`.

Comment: works beautifully, submit it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I do not think that this kind of method combination is a good fit for your problem.  You actually do not want to annotate your fuel calculation with "ah, and I also arrive somewhere", and you do not want to annotate arriving somewhere with "ah, and I also need to calculate whether I arrive at all".  You want to do a `move`, which might be composed of `prepare`, `fly`, `arrive`, sequentially.  Method combination unnecessarily couples things that conceptually are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the fuel calculation in an `:AROUND` method and turn the two `:AFTER` methods into primary methods. `:AROUND` methods must use `CALL-NEXT-METHOD` manually to call the primary method, so you can do something like `(when (sufficient-fuel) (call-next-method))` to only call it when there is enough fuel.

Answer (score 2):

Note that *conditions* are not necessarily *errors*. An error is a specific condition, where *normal program execution cannot continue correctly without some form of intervention*.
The *condition system* can be used for other *situations*, too.

Common Lisp also has `catch` and `throw` for non-local control transfer. The *throw* will be caught by a *catch*, within its *dynamic extent*, using a specific *catch tag*.

The outer `:around` method establishes an exit catcher for the tag `exit-move`.

```
(defmethod move :around (ship destination)
  (catch 'exit-move (call-next-method)))
```

The inner methods, like the primary methods can transfer control to the above `catch`, by using `throw` with the right catch tag `exit-move`. The primary method will always be used *inside* the *around method*, thus the *catch tag* will always be throwable from it.

```
(defmethod move (ship destination)
  (print (list :primary ship destination))
  (when (thing-happened-p)
   (throw 'exit-move nil)))
```